# hardware acceleration for ffmpeg is not working

Tags: ffmpeg, gpu, cpu

I download cuda driver for my nvidia

but it still does not use my GPU, it still using cpu.

how can i make it use GPU.

i heard about hardware acceleration as well but thats not working.

It has to be h.264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear.

From what I have read, it looks like you are trying to do h.264 encoding using your Nvidia GPU card.

Try this command and add your other codec or change the codec you use.

But usually, this will encode a file you have to mp4 using GPU.

`ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -i input.mp4 -c:v h264_nvenc -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset slow output.mp4`